# Uniquename function in mdx script

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, reporting-services, mdx

I really need your help.

For a SSRS report, I have this mdx script:

```
select 
 {[Geographie].[Commune].[AHUY], [Geographie].[Commune].[BRETENIERE]} on columns
,{[Activite].[Branche].&[B], [Activite].[Branche].&[C]} on rows
from [ACSEL2]
where ([Measures].[CATTC], [Perimetre].[Perimetre].&[2], [Temps].[Annee].&[2006])
```

Please, I need to have the uniquename for the members that I have in columns

```
({[Geographie].[Commune].[AHUY], [Geographie].[Commune].[BRETENIERE]})
```

Please Can U help me to write this mdx script ?

Lidou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    WITH 
-- Geography metadata
MEMBER [Measures].[Geographie]
AS StrToValue ( @SelectionGeographie + ".Hierarchy.Currentmember.Uniquename" )
MEMBER [Measures].[Geographie_Label]
AS StrToValue( @SelectionGeographie + ".Hierarchy.CurrentMember.Member_Caption" )

SELECT NON EMPTY {
[Measures].[Geographie],
[Measures].[Geographie_Label],
[Measures].[11 VA]


} ON COLUMNS, 

( STRTOSET ( "{" + @SelectionGeographie + "}") ,


    STRTOSET   ("{" + @SelectionActivite + "}" ))


ON ROWS

 FROM [MyCube]

WHERE STRTOTUPLE ( "(" +@Annee + "," + @Perimetre + ")" )
```

Comment: My  problem is that when I run this query in report mode without parameters  that works.

And when I put one value parameter that works too.

But, when I put multi-value in parameters, I have "null" results for my colums with multi-value.

I think that it's caused by  

.Hierarchy.Currentmember.Uniquename


Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Declare a member using `With` statement, like this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[UniqueName] as [Geographie].[Commune].CurrentMember.UniqueName
Select
--Your select here
```

More details on [CurrentMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms144948.aspx)

Comment: Thank U Michele for your answer.

Comment: So. is it possible to use a multi-value parameter with the uniquename function ?

Comment: Hi michele,

Thank U for your answer.

I want to create a report with parameter member.

This is my mdx dataset: